# Angularjs ng-selected populate

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate the currently selected item in angular js.

The currently selected item is that with the id in `event.email.chases[0].id`

and I am trying to match it to a select box populated from `case.activeChases`

This does what I want so far, which updates whenever the select box changes.

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    name="chase"
    id="chase"
    ng-model="customer.chase"
    ng-change="addEmailToChase(customer.chase.id, event.email.id)"
    ng-options="cor as cor.emails[0].subject for cor in case.activeChases">
    <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```

I need to find the chase in `activeChases` with `activeChases[x].id = event.email.chases[0].id`, so the correct value is selected upon the page load.
Could I possibly do this all within a `ng-selected` attribute?

Comment: can you put together a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: You could just run a loop to find where those id's meet, cant you?

Comment: is that possible inside `ng-selected`?

Comment: what i mean is you should run your loop on ng-change to parse active chases and email chases. I don't know how your data is structured, so I cant really help you much. put together a demo, snippet, plunker, etc and it'll be easier to help.

Comment: So I need the correct selection only at the page load, not at `ng-change`.

Comment: I've updated the question, I don't think I made that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was my answer:

```
                            <select
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="chase"
                                    id="chase"
                                    ng-model="event.email.chases[0].id"
                                    ng-change="addEmailToChase(event.email.chases[0].id, event.email.id)"
                                    ng-options="cor.id[0] as cor.emails[0].subject for cor in case.activeChases">
                            </select>
```

I wanted the default value to be `event.email.chases[0].id` in the select, so I just set `ng-model` to that, and changed the first option to `cor.id[0]` to use id in index.

I chose a random name for `ng-model` which was `customer.chase` which made no sense. `event` represents an ajax loaded form element so its safe for me to do this in my scope.

Also worth noting that the id in `cor.id[0]` is actually in a size one array due to incorrect design in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your model and your ng-options, the object should be the same if you want an "auto-selected"

without a jsfiddle it's hard to reproduce your situation but I tryed something like that

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.case = {
    activeChases: [{
      emails: [{
        subject: 'toto'
      }]
    }, {
      emails: [{
        subject: 'tata'
      }]
    }]
  };

  // set "default value"
  $scope.customer = {
    chase: $scope.case.activeChases[1]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" name="chase" id="chase" ng-model="customer.chase" ng-change="addEmailToChase(customer.chase.id, event.email.id)" ng-options="cor as cor.emails[0].subject for cor in case.activeChases">
    <option value="">None</option>
  </select>
</section>
```